# Angular: Invalid configuration object. Webpack has been initialised using a configuration object that does not match the API schema

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, webpack, single-page-application

My project was working fine until I copied the whole project folder to another machine and this is what I am getting on the new machine now:

```
Invalid configuration object. Webpack has been initialised using a configuration object that does not match the API schema.
 - configuration.entry should be one of these:
   function | object { <key>: non-empty string | [non-empty string] } | non-empty string | [non-empty string]
   -> The entry point(s) of the compilation.
   Details:
    * configuration.entry should be an instance of function
      -> A Function returning an entry object, an entry string, an entry array or a promise to these things.
    * configuration.entry['styles'] should be a string.
      -> The string is resolved to a module which is loaded upon startup.
    * configuration.entry['styles'] should not contain the item 'G:\MyProjects\kud2\node_modules\ngx-bootstrap\datepicker\bs-datepicker.css' twice.
    * configuration.entry should be a string.
      -> An entry point without name. The string is resolved to a module which is loaded upon startup.
    * configuration.entry should be an array:
      [non-empty string]
WebpackOptionsValidationError: Invalid configuration object. Webpack has been initialised using a configuration object that does not match the API schema.
 - configuration.entry should be one of these:
   function | object { <key>: non-empty string | [non-empty string] } | non-empty string | [non-empty string]
   -> The entry point(s) of the compilation.
   Details:
    * configuration.entry should be an instance of function
      -> A Function returning an entry object, an entry string, an entry array or a promise to these things.
    * configuration.entry['styles'] should be a string.
      -> The string is resolved to a module which is loaded upon startup.
    * configuration.entry['styles'] should not contain the item 'G:\MyProjects\kud2\node_modules\ngx-bootstrap\datepicker\bs-datepicker.css' twice.
    * configuration.entry should be a string.
      -> An entry point without name. The string is resolved to a module which is loaded upon startup.
    * configuration.entry should be an array:
      [non-empty string]
    at webpack (G:\MyProjects\kud2\node_modules\webpack\lib\webpack.js:31:9)
    at Observable.rxjs_1.Observable.obs [as _subscribe] (G:\MyProjects\kud2\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-webpack\src\webpack-dev-server\index.js:39:37)
    at Observable._trySubscribe (G:\MyProjects\kud2\node_modules\rxjs\internal\Observable.js:44:25)
    at Observable.subscribe (G:\MyProjects\kud2\node_modules\rxjs\internal\Observable.js:30:22)
    at G:\MyProjects\kud2\node_modules\rxjs\internal\util\subscribeTo.js:22:31
    at Object.subscribeToResult (G:\MyProjects\kud2\node_modules\rxjs\internal\util\subscribeToResult.js:10:45)
    at MergeMapSubscriber._innerSub (G:\MyProjects\kud2\node_modules\rxjs\internal\operators\mergeMap.js:82:29)
    at MergeMapSubscriber._tryNext (G:\MyProjects\kud2\node_modules\rxjs\internal\operators\mergeMap.js:76:14)
    at MergeMapSubscriber._next (G:\MyProjects\kud2\node_modules\rxjs\internal\operators\mergeMap.js:59:18)
    at MergeMapSubscriber.Subscriber.next (G:\MyProjects\kud2\node_modules\rxjs\internal\Subscriber.js:67:18)
    at TapSubscriber._next (G:\MyProjects\kud2\node_modules\rxjs\internal\operators\tap.js:65:26)
    at TapSubscriber.Subscriber.next (G:\MyProjects\kud2\node_modules\rxjs\internal\Subscriber.js:67:18)
    at MergeMapSubscriber.notifyNext (G:\MyProjects\kud2\node_modules\rxjs\internal\operators\mergeMap.js:92:26)
    at InnerSubscriber._next (G:\MyProjects\kud2\node_modules\rxjs\internal\InnerSubscriber.js:28:21)
    at InnerSubscriber.Subscriber.next (G:\MyProjects\kud2\node_modules\rxjs\internal\Subscriber.js:67:18)
    at MergeMapSubscriber.notifyNext (G:\MyProjects\kud2\node_modules\rxjs\internal\operators\mergeMap.js:92:26)
```

**Package.json**

```
{
  "name": "kud2",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~7.2.0",
    "@angular/common": "~7.2.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "~7.2.0",
    "@angular/core": "~7.2.0",
    "@angular/forms": "~7.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~7.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~7.2.0",
    "@angular/router": "~7.2.0",
    "bootstrap": "^3.4.1",
    "core-js": "^2.5.4",
    "ngx-bootstrap": "^4.1.1",
    "rxjs": "~6.3.3",
    "tslib": "^1.9.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.3.2",
    "zone.js": "~0.8.26"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.13.0",
    "@angular/cli": "~7.3.9",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~7.2.0",
    "@angular/language-service": "~7.2.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.8.8",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/node": "~8.9.4",
    "codelyzer": "~4.5.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.99.1",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~4.0.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.2",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "~5.4.0",
    "ts-node": "~7.0.0",
    "tslint": "~5.11.0",
    "typescript": "~3.2.2",
    "webpack": "^4.31.0"
  }
}
```

I have tried reinstalling webpack but to no avail.

```
npm uninstall webpack --save-dev
npm install webpack --save-dev
```

Any ideas what could be causing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> configuration.entry['styles'] should not contain the item
>   'G:\MyProjects\kud2\node_modules\ngx-bootstrap\datepicker\bs-datepicker.css'
>   twice.

I see in the log there are some duplicate styles entry config could you check it to see if you are using it in the project ?

Comment: Yeah I removed it. It's still not working. It was working on the previous machine even with the two \bs-datepicker.css references

Comment: The code which was running fine on the previous machine also randomly decided stop working after a while. Turns out it was indeed because of duplicate entries in style. I had tried removing duplicate entries before but it did not work but that was because removed the wrong duplicate entry. 
`"node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css","./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",`  should have been `"node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"`

Comment: Glad to help . Cheers

Comment: I'm facing the same problem: .../node_modules/ngx-bootstrap/datepicker/bs-datepicker.css' twice. But the I look in the node_modules files I can see there is only 1 entry of bs-datepicker.css
How can I solve this error?

Answer (score 2):

I have faced same problem, this is how i resolved it. I was using two styles in angular.json

```
"styles": [
    "./node_modules/@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/deeppurple-amber.css",
    "src/styles.css",
    "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
    "src/styles.css"

 ],
```

as you see there are two `"src/style.css"`

The new code

```
"styles": [
   "./node_modules/@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/deeppurple-amber.css",
   "src/styles.css",
   "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"

],
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this same issue after running the command:

ng add ngx-bootstrap  --component tooltip

This added an additional "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" reference to the angular.json, removing it fixed the error